# React navigation get title of previous screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using React Navigation 5.x for my react native app. I've got a stack navigator with several screens like dashboard and invoices. My screen invoices has a custom header so I'm not using the React Navigation header options. Because of that I'm not able to show the title of the previous screen in the back button like React Navigation's header is using.

Of course I'm able to put a custom GoBack button inside the custom header but I'd rather use the title of the previous screen.

Is there a way to get the title of the previous screen/route wherefrom the user came? Tried several things like using dangerouslyGetParent() but that wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

you can send current screen name as a parameter

```
props.navigation.navigate("invoices", { previous_screen: "dashboard" } )
```

and reading that parameter in the next screen

```
props.navigation.state.params.previous_screen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the `previous` prop passed to the custom header.

Example:

```js
function Header({ scene, previous }) {
  const { options } = scene.descriptor;

  let previousTitle;

  // The label for the back button shows the title of the previous screen
  // If a custom label is specified, we use it, otherwise use previous screen's title
  if (options.headerBackTitle !== undefined) {
    previousTitle = options.headerBackTitle;
  } else if (previous) {
    const o = previous.descriptor.options;

    previousTitle =
      typeof o.headerTitle !== 'function' && o.headerTitle !== undefined
        ? o.headerTitle
        : o.title !== undefined
        ? o.title
        : previous.route.routeName;
  }

  // Rest of the header content
}
```